# how to copy used and unused code in Chrome inspect coverage with just one click?

Tags: optimization, code-coverage, developer-tools, web-inspector, google-chrome-console

I'm struggling to efficiently copy both used and unused code highlighted in Chrome's inspect coverage. While I've explored Chrome DevTools documentation and online forums, I haven't found a straightforward solution. Specifically, I want to copy the code with a single click and separate the active (green line) code for further analysis. Any guidance on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: inspect coverage]